# The correctness of NTT algorithm

Tags: lattice-crypto, dilithium, polynomial

When directly invoking the ntt and invntt function in Dilithium's code with any polynomial $a \in R_q$, I get a unexpected running result: $NTT(a) \neq iNTT(NTT(a))$.
And in the test code of Dilithium(\test\test_mul.c), if want get an correct running, we need multiple the coefficients with -114592 before invoking the poly_invntt_tomont function. Why we need perform the extra process? If an different prime number is used, how can we compute such a constant value?

```
poly_ntt(&c);
for (j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
    c.coeffs[j] = (int64_t)c.coeffs[j] * 114592 % Q;
}
poly_invntt_tomont(&c);
for (j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
    if((c.coeffs[j] - a.coeffs[j]) % Q) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR in ntt/invntt: c[%d] = %d != %d\n", j, c.coeffs[j]%Q, a.coeffs[j]);
    }
}

poly_naivemul(&c, &a, &b);
poly_ntt(&a);
poly_ntt(&b);
poly_pointwise_montgomery(&d, &a, &b);
poly_invntt_tomont(&d);
```

Comment: It also happends when running the code of [Kyber](https://github.com/pq-crystals/kyber). But the test code does not check whethre $iNTT(NTT(a)) = a$, so I don't know how to check the correctness of NTT code.